# How does Range affect damage in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

*This question acts as a followup to [How is incoming damage calculated in Fallout 4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/358314/how-is-incoming-damage-calculated-in-fallout-4)*

I have the formula for how damage is calculated normally, but I am under the impression that at least ballistic weapons have a range modifier to damage, e.g. they do less damage at greater range.
What is the formula for this damage modification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A weapon's range value is the maximum range within which a weapon does maximum damage. Exceeding it, the damage output will increasingly decrease until at twice the range and after, the damage output will be halved.

---

- **A weapon's 'Range'** (which is [likely](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136924703563) in in-game meters or (more appropriately) feet) **is the distance after which a projectile's speed (or damage) deteriorates**, or, in the words of the [Fandom](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Range#Fallout_4) page:

  > the furthest distance that a particular weapon will deal its maximum damage outside of V.A.T.S. and additionally affect the chance to hit a target when using V.A.T.S.

  It can thus be interpreted as "*maximum optimal range*".
- According to the *Damage Resistance* page on [Fandom](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Damage_Resistance), **weapon damage beyond this maximum range will decrease the damage up to 50% when the range is doubled**:

  `PaperDamage` = `WeaponBaseDamage` x `RangeMulti` ( x Perk 1 × Perk 2 × ⋯)

  where

  > `RangeMulti` is 1.0 at 100% *WeaponRange* or closer, 0.5 at 200% of `WeaponRange` or farther, and scales from 1.0 to 0.5 as range increases from 100% to 200% of `WeaponRange`.

  This applies to projectile, close-combat, and energy weapons.
  From some point onward, the damage will drop to 0, but this is beyond the vanilla maximum NPC draw distance.

  EDIT: each weapon has an `Out-of-Range Multiplier` value. It is true that for most weapons this value is `0.5`, but some weapons deviate from this (like the *[Assaultron Laser](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361829/how-much-damage-does-the-assaultron-head-laser-do)*, which only decreases to `0.8`).

Comment: The meter is the basic unit of distance in the International System of Units (SI), the world's standardized system of measurement. So no. Feet is not more appropriate.

Comment: @nr_aus Don't you think we might have different concepts of "appropriateness" in this context, a term that is quite subjective to begin with? The USA still mostly uses feet, and Fallout 4 is an American game. I *think* I wrote "more appropriately" because the [in-game units correspond with feet](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Unit) rather than metres.

Comment: Your argument isn't with me, its with the International System of Units.

Comment: @nr_aus I don't have an argument: you told me "feet is not more appropriate", and I gave you a reason why it is more appropriate *in this context*. This is completely moot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From the ck, the range is range where the weapon can do the max damage.

Min: Distance in units where damage falloff begins.
Max: Distance in units where damage falloff ends.

Units are in feets

Source ck: https://www.creationkit.com/fallout4/index.php?title=Weapon

When applying range mods to weapons, one can test it by going into V.A.T.S. and selecting settlers or turrets, turrets being the better choice due to being stationary; queued shots will indicate less damage once one is past the range limit.

Testing myself, Between the min and max range, the reduction is progressive from 100% to around 30%.