# How much damage does the Assaultron head laser do?

Tags: fallout-4

While looking at armor, I attempted to pick out a series of representative weapons and damaging effects that one could encounter out in the wasteland. Deathclaw claw attacks, mininukes, and super-sledges are easily found and calculated, but I can't find the damage value for an Assaultron head laser anywhere. What's the damage value for this weapon? Or is it a true "insta-kill" weapon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Creation Kit, **the unmodified Assaultron Head Laser does 100 base damage of the Energy type**:

[image: Creation Kit entry for Fallout 4's Assaultron's laser weapon]

Based on some testing, using my unclothed and static level 63 player character with bare damage reduction (*Astoundingly Awesome 3* (-5% DMG from robots), *Lone Wanderer 2* (-30% DMG)), I got up to 1550 DMG* from a single shot, translating to **+/- 2330 DMG for a single, constant, and full shot**, without the damage reduction.

Unlike chargeable weapons that the player can use (e.g. the Gauss Rifle), the Assaultron's head weapon does not have charging information on the Weapon sheet seen above. The charge time of the laser weapon can be found in the *AssaultronHeadModScript.psc* file: the integer `laserChargeTime` has a value of `15`, which seems to correspond with the time in seconds in-game. As other charging weapons have an exponential increase in DMG as they are charged, I suggest something similar happens here.
Something else to be taken into account, is that the shot itself lasts for a few (around 4) seconds.

According to [this article](https://www.creationkit.com/fallout4/index.php?title=Talk:Weapons) on weapons in the Creation Kit, the *Automatic* flag ignores the `Attack Delay` value and calculates based on `Speed`. `Speed` for this weapon has a value of `1`, which translates to 90 RPM *in-game*, which is 90 every ten seconds, or 9 Rounds per Second (that is, still, with reservations, and assuming this particular weapon is not (completely) controlled by a script - most values being standard `1` begs to differ).

---

I did additional tests, with a new Level 1 character without any perks on Normal difficulty.

<sup>As a side note, the differences between the values of the first tests - using my Level 63 character - and the ones presented below can be partially explained by the former having been carried out on Hard difficulty (taking the 1550 DMG and subtracting 1/3 (on Hard one takes 1.5x damage) makes for 1033 DMG, resulting in +/- 1410 DMG raw damage. This is still a bit steep, however, so I'll just assume unknown variables account for it - this is no rocket science; this is Rocket 69 science).</sup>

Running around in her undergarments, the damage received was:

```
1. 1278
2. 1065
3. 1167
4. 918
5. 1278
```

The 1278 is interesting, as it occurs twice and is also the highest number: I think this could be the actual cap. Or coincidence.

Wearing Military Fatigues and a Green Rag Hat, both using Ballistic Weave Mk V (resulting in Damage Resistance of 220 and Energy Resistance of 235), the damage incurred was as follows:

```
1. 137
2. 394
3. 167
4. 472
5. 343
6. 463
```

This disproves the hypothesis proffered in the comments that the Assaultron Laser weapon is "*an "automatic" weapon with a damage per shot of 100 and 6 shots per second over four seconds*".

Apart from the reservation mentioned before*, the conspicuous and here even greater differences between values can also have been caused by Weapon Spread, since my character's distance to the attacking Assaultron varied a lot during testing. This suspicion is aroused by the laser beam initially always seemingly spiralling for a second or two before it stabilizes.

Most of the weapon spread data can be found in the [*Aim Model*](https://www.creationkit.com/fallout4/index.php?title=AimModel) of the weapon:

[image: Aim Model for the Assaultron Head Laser]

Compared to other weapons found in the game, this is extremely precise, though.

The Range, according to the Weapon sheet, is also seemingly excellent, but as all other usable weapons have these Min and Max values multiplied by an integer in the standard or adjusted weapon barrel mod (an OMOD or Object Mod file with `fminrange` and `fmaxrange` values), it's hard to tell what the in-game value really is.

Since the weapon itself is controlled by an AI (both in- and out-of-game) that often has trouble finding her target, values like Range and Weapon Spread ultimately don't matter that much, and **we might as well attribute these inconsistent results to the Assaultron AI's lacking tracking algorithms.**

Hopefully this long-winded addendum sheds some additional light on the matter.

<sup>* The laser attack wasn't a completely direct and constant hit, which accounts for the slightly varying damage received.</sup>

Comment: I'll see if I can dig up more information, but for now this is as much as I can find.

Comment: That is far more information than I was able to find, thank you. When I work the math on what the base damage value for that much final damage is I'll put it in the comments here. And thank you for not simply saying "100", that doesn't feel like a 100 Energy Damage attack.

Comment: I wonder if it the raw damage is maybe 2400, 600 per second, charging from 100 to 600 in 15 seconds. That might at least be a good hypothesis to start from.

Comment: If that's true, and it's certainly checked as "automatic", then the question becomes how many individual "hits" per second does it cause that are each individually counted in the damage formula. Is it possible that it deals 6 "hits" per second, and the charge time is just the delay from the activation to the first "shot" from the laser? Each hit would be damage 100 in that case.

Comment: If it's an "automatic" weapon with a damage per shot of 100 and 6 shots per second over four seconds, the way to confirm it would be to wear Ballistic Weave V Military Fatigues and a Ballistic Weave V Green Rag Hat, then take the full blast. In total, you should take ~888 damage. If it's more like 850, one of the "shots" missed (each "shot" would deal ~37 damage). I'd test this, but I don't have a character at a high-enough level for that.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the amount of testing you've gone through for this. Based on the numbers you got with the Military Fatigues and Green Rag Cap, the damage over four seconds is between 263 and 651 damage, so I'd assume closer to 651, which is inconsistent with the damage taken while wearing no armor on the new character. I'm also not sure if this is your character with Astoundingly Awesome 3 and Lone Wanderer 2 in play or not, which might make up the difference.

Comment: The math unfortunately breaks when wearing nothing, as your ER is technically 0 and therefore the fraction and damage go infinite, unless there's a minimum I don't know about.

Comment: The second character did not have AA3 or LW2: she was a completely new character. And what math breaks when wearing nothing?

Comment: The damage equation (for energy damage) is finalDamage=paperDamage*(paperDamage*0.15/energyResistance)^0.365. If energyResistance ever goes to zero, then you're dividing by zero, which a computer either reads as "undefined" or "infinite". And I was referring to the high-level character, not the new one.

Comment: Since my previous comment, I was able to do more research on my own. There is a minimum value for the actual damage reduction of 1% to fix the previously-mentioned math error. I would also agree with Joachim's remark about tracking algorithms (for such an accurate weapon, moving slightly out of the way would easily result in a low hit %), and add that a combination of that plus range modifiers (depending on the range of the test) plus difficulty level modifiers may indicate that my theory about an automatic weapon with 6 shots per second is actually correct.

Comment: @BrandonOlson Cool, thanks for the additional info. I'll look into it more later.