# How do Sneak Attacks affect damage in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

*This question acts as a followup to [How is incoming damage calculated in Fallout 4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/358314/how-is-incoming-damage-calculated-in-fallout-4)*

I have the formula for how damage is calculated normally, but I know that damage is modified when the condition "sneak attack" is applied. Where does this modification occur in the damage formula (paperDamage, baseWeaponDamage, finalDamage, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `FinalDamage`, of which the formula [is as follows](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Damage_Resistance#Fallout_4):

> `FinalDamage` = `PaperDamage` x `SneakAttackMulti` x `DamageCoeff` × `HeadshotMulti`

**The** `SneakAttackMulti` **is the value you're looking for.**
This value directly corresponds to the [*Ninja* skill](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Ninja#Fallout_4) sneak attack multiplier bonuses (e.g. Rank 1 having `2.5` ranged and `4` melee attack damage multiplier), but is, as mentioned in the comments, influenced by other skills and effects (like the [*Mister Sandman* perk](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Mister_Sandman#Fallout_4), which grants a(n additional) multiplier of up to `0.5` (under certain circumstances), or [the unique *Pickman's Blade*](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Pickman%27s_Blade), which adds `0.6` to `SneakAttackMulti`).

If requesting this information is also intended for playthroughs, be sure - unless you use the [Unofficial Patch](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/4598) - to select the associated skills in the right order, as pointed out [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/164592-fallout-4/72897086?page=2#22), or you might miss out on the full bonus.

Comment: Interesting side-note to add since I'm looking at the full equation, SneakAttackMulti and HeadShotMulti are, as far as I can tell, the only true "doubling factors" as far as damage is concerned. Doubling the weapon damage itself kind of does do that, but it also factors into DamageCoeff.

Comment: `DamageCoeff` is mostly damage reduction, so mostly based on the *target's* armour.

Comment: Generally true, but the sneaky factor is that it's based on the quotient of your damage divided by the target's armor. So, it does factor into that equation, with the general trend being that high levels of armor increasingly help protect against greater levels of damage while not significantly increasing your protection against lower levels of damage.